# Search for a text from a column, in another column in SQL/Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns

| UserName | ManagerList |
| --- | --- |
| Abhi | Ayush; Abhi; Kirti |
| Suman | Ayush; Priti; Kirti |
| Satish | Ayush; Priti; Kirti; Satish |

I want to see if user in username is present in ManagerList in Oracle SQL

output

| UserName | ManagerList | is_available |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abhi | Ayush; Abhi; Kirti | Y |
| Suman | Ayush; Priti; Kirti | N |
| Satish | Ayush; Priti; Kirti; Satish | Y |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware of *false positives* with either `instr` or `like`. I don't know whether it is possible, but - if someone (of managers) has more than one name (which might be; there are people with more than a single first name), you'd get wrong result. For example:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (username, managerlist)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'Abhi', 'Ayush Abhi Priti; Kirti; Satish' FROM DUAL)
  5  SELECT UserName,
  6         ManagerList,
  7         CASE WHEN INSTR (ManagerList, UserName) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
  8            AS is_available_instr,              --> Jonas
  9         CASE WHEN ManagerList LIKE '%' || UserName || '%' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
 10            is_available_like                   --> Ankit
 11    FROM test;

USERNAME        MANAGERLIST                     IS_AVAILABLE_INSTR   IS_AVAILABLE_LIKE
--------------- ------------------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Abhi            Ayush Abhi Priti; Kirti; Satish Y                    Y

SQL>
```

See? Manager named "Ayush Abhi Priti" does contain "Abhi", but - is `Y` correct result in that case?

---

Consider applying delimiters to avoid such a result:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (username, managerlist)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'Abhi', 'Ayush; Abhi; Kirti' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'Suman', 'Ayush; Priti; Kirti' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'Satish', 'Ayush; Priti; Kirti; Satish' FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'Abhi', 'Ayush Abhi Priti; Kirti; Satish' FROM DUAL)
 11  SELECT username,
 12         managerlist,
 13         --
 14         CASE
 15            WHEN INSTR (';' || managerlist || ';', '; ' || username || ';') > 0 THEN 'Y'
 16            ELSE 'N'
 17         END AS is_available
 18    FROM test;

USERNAME        MANAGERLIST                     IS_AVAILABLE
--------------- ------------------------------- ---------------
Abhi            Ayush; Abhi; Kirti              Y
Suman           Ayush; Priti; Kirti             N
Satish          Ayush; Priti; Kirti; Satish     Y
Abhi            Ayush Abhi Priti; Kirti; Satish N     --> previously, this one was wrong, marked as "Y"

SQL>
```

Comment: Right, @Jonas. That's something like having employee whose name is "Jonas". There's a manager whose name is "Jonas Marcus Metzler". So, is "Jonas" also a manager? I think not.

Comment: Yes, I agree, as said thank you for adding this point. It's of course cleaner, even if not maybe not required. I added a note to my answer ;)

Comment: Yes, I know, you're welcome, @Jonas :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `INSTR` function:

```
SELECT 
  UserName, ManagerList, 
  CASE WHEN INSTR(ManagerList,UserName) > 0  
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N' END AS is_available
FROM yourtable;
```

Read about the function in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSTR.html#GUID-47E3A7C4-ED72-458D-A1FA-25A9AD3BE113).

See this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ruRoOY9K) based on your data.

Note: @Littlefoot proposed a cleaner way how to use the function in this use case, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77110003/18794826). I don't know if you need to do so, but it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

I think simply LIKE operator will work for you -

```
SELECT UserName, ManagerList, CASE WHEN ManagerList LIKE '%' || UserName  || '%' THEN
                                        'Y'
                                   ELSE 'N'
                              END is_available
  FROM your_table;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/HNkit2Je)

Answer (score 0):

Use either `LIKE` or `INSTR` to compare the `managerlist` with the username **AND** include the surrounding delimiter characters for both:

```sql
SELECT username,
       managerlist, 
       CASE
       WHEN '; ' || managerlist || '; ' LIKE '%; ' || username || '; %'
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END AS is_available
FROM   table_name
```

or:

```sql
SELECT username,
       managerlist, 
       CASE
       WHEN INSTR('; ' || managerlist || '; ', '; ' || username || '; ') > 0
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END AS is_available
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (UserName, ManagerList) AS
SELECT 'Alice', 'Beryl; Alice; Carol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', 'Alice; Carol; Debra' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', 'Beryl; Alice; Carol' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alice', 'Beryl; NotAlice; Carol' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| USERNAME | MANAGERLIST | IS_AVAILABLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Beryl; Alice; Carol | Y |
| Beryl | Alice; Carol; Debra | N |
| Carol | Beryl; Alice; Carol | Y |
| Alice | Beryl; NotAlice; Carol | N |

If you just use `INSTR` or `LIKE` to naively match values *without* the surrounding delimiters then you may get false-positives when you match a partial term and you would match `NotAlice` when you should only match `Alice`. Including the delimiters forces the match to be a complete term.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V8GYbQam)